# Package javax mail does not exist

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have written a code which, when I try to compile it, gives me an error message PACKAGE JAVAX.MAIL DOES NOT EXIST. So I downloaded JAVAMAIL-1.4.7 and extracted the zipped file and saved it on my temporary files folder. I realise that I have to modify my java code so that it can access the temporary files by giving my code a destination path, but I don't know how to do this. What line do I include in my java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put it in the temporary folder.

You need to include it within your application. Create a structure for your app that is something like this:

```
MyApp
  src (put java code here)
  lib (put 'downloaded code' libraries here)
```

Put the downloaded JAVAMAIL-1.4.7.jar file into lib

Then at the top of your class, you will need the following line.

```
import javax.mail.*;
```

Try it, if it doesn't work, then update your question with your project structure and actual code, so it's possible to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I should have included the code in my question. The following is the first 20% of my code (it seems I cannot include the whole code because I get an error message "too long by 2000 characters) :import javax.mail.*; 
import javax.mail.internet.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class SendMailUsingAuthentication { 
    private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "gemini.jvmhost.com"; //or simply "localhost" 
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "me@domain.com"; 
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD = "secret"; 
    private static final Stri